# Import JSON File into InfluxDB

Tags: python, json, indentation, importerror, influxdb

I want to import a JSON into InfluxDB using Python.I wrote the code for writing the data into JSON as

**with open('outfile.json', 'a') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile,indent=4, sort_keys=True)**

Then when I import this JSON to InfluxDB as, ***db.write_points(json_data)*** it raises an error as follows:

**raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")**

**ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded**

Is there an issue with my JSON indentation?

If yes, then how do I resolve it?

JSON is pretty big in size(over 20mB)

Comment: Have you solve this issue?